# Turning a string into a list of all its non-alphanumeric chars in Python

Tags: python, regex, list

How do I scan a string for all its non-alphanumeric characters?

So far I have the following:

```
pattern = re.compile('\W')
```

Comment: Could you describe, why do you need this, what's the use case?

Comment: Please explain the problem clearly, with the sample input, expected output. As it is, the question might get closed soon for not being clear.

Comment: I just want a way to get a list of all non-alphanumeric characters in Python

Comment: @user3175999 Just to be clear, you want all the unicode characters as well?

Comment: You might want to clear the confusion here: The Q asks to scan a string, whereas in comments you say that you want all non-alphanumeric symbols(not characters) in python. I've answered assuming you want the latter one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give the set of non-alphanumeric symbols:

```
set(string.printable) - set(string.letters) - set(string.digits)
```

Or using RE:

```
re.findall("\W", string.printable)
```

Comment: @user3175999 `import string`

Comment: is there a way to make a set into a list

Comment: just do `list(set(string.printable) - set(string.letters) - set(string.digits))`

Answer (score 0):

Example scanning strings using standard library string methods.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

```
charlist = ['google', 'stack-overflow', 'twitter', '#$!word']
["".join([y for y in x if not y.isalpha()]) for x in charlist]
out[1]: ['', '-', '', '#$!']
```